# how to fix my AutoHotkey active window checker (fileappend)

Tags: windows, window, autohotkey

It is supposed to put an entry in a text file **each** time a new window is active, instead it constantly loops and puts thousands of entries while the window is active, if anyone is capable of rectifying this I would be grateful.

```
loop
{
    if new_window = %window_title%
        new_window = diff
    else
    {
        WinGetActiveTitle, window_title
        fileappend, %window_title%`n, C:\mydirectory\myname.txt
        new_window = %window_title%
    }
}
```

Any help able to be provided would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a timer to check for a new window every 0.5 seconds.

```
#Persistent
prev_window := ""
settimer, check_window, 500
return

check_window:
WinGetActiveTitle, active_window
if  (active_window != prev_window) {
    fileappend, %active_window%`n, myname.txt
    prev_window := active_window
}
return
```

The same could be accomplished in a loop:

```
prev_window := ""
loop 
{
    WinGetActiveTitle, active_window
    if  (active_window != prev_window) {
        fileappend, %active_window%`n, myname.txt
        prev_window := active_window
    }
    sleep, 500
}
return
```

Answer (score -2):

You should probably put a SetTimer that checks active window title in some time interval (100ms or something) and compare to previously checked window tile - and if it has changed then write to file.